# Can there be 2 canvas class on one screen display in j2me

Tags: java-me, canvas, midp, lcdui

Can I have a Canvas class and Custom Item shown on one screen?

Comment: text of this question is the same as of another one, is that intentional? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273257/can-i-have-customitem-and-canvas-class-on-same-screen-in-j2me

Answer (score -1):

yes.you can create a canvas.Then create a custom item and append in canvas.Then you display the canvas.Here custom item also displayed inside in the canvas