# Can I have CustomItem and Canvas class on same Screen in j2me

Tags: java-me, canvas, midp, lcdui

Can I have CustomItem object and Canvas class on same screen in j2me?

I created a Tab Menu which extends Canvas and then a custom Header class which extends CustomItem class so I want it to integrate in one form. Can I do it?

Comment: i created a Tab Menu which extends Canvas  ... and then a custom Header class which extends CustomItem class ... so i want it to integrate in one form .. can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

As long as *Tab Menu* extends Canvas, there is no way to integrate it into Form with [MIDP 2 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html).

To integrate it into Form I would probably just redesign that *Tab Menu* to extend CustomItem instead of Canvas. That way would make it possible to have it on same form screen along with your *Header CustomItem*.